Make PopUpMenu appear behind keyboard in Compose?
I'm currently working on a dropdown menu in my Android app. It works well, however, the keyboard always end up behind the popup menu, and I want the keyboard to cover it up. When I say PopUpMenu, I'm really referring to a drop down menu as seen here.
DropdownMenu(
        properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
        expanded = expandedState,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {}



Use the PopupProperties and set the focusable property to true. This will ensure the dropdown menu doesn't interfere with the keyboard input.
DropdownMenu(
    expanded = expandedState,
    onDismissRequest = { expandedState = false },
    properties = PopupProperties(
        focusable = true // Makes the popup interact with the keyboard properly
    )
) {
    // Your menu items here
}

Adjust the Z-Index (if needed): If the dropdown menu overlaps the keyboard, you can control the z-index to prioritize the keyboard:
Modifier.zIndex(0f) // Set the dropdown below the keyboard

Manually Handle Keyboard Visibility: You can also use LocalSoftwareKeyboardController to detect the keyboard state and adjust the dropdown menu accordingly.
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

DropdownMenu(
    expanded = expandedState,
    onDismissRequest = {
        expandedState = false
        keyboardController?.hide() // Dismiss the keyboard
    },
    properties = PopupProperties(focusable = true)
) {
    // Menu items
}

This setup ensures the dropdown menu is properly hidden when the keyboard is in focus, preventing any visual conflicts.

Using the z index didnt work and I need focusable to be false to allow typing, otherwise it auto focuses on the first element of the list and stops me from typing
